# Disable 'Suggested Names' with latest Visual Studio 2017 Update?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I've just updated to the newest Visual Studio 2017 update (enterprise) through the 'Extensions and Updates' window.

I've noticed they have added 'Suggested names' to intellisense when using snippets (i.e `propfull`), which seems to overwrite the value you have typed when pressing 'tab' (the normal way to cycle through items).

This is super annoying, does anyone know how to disable it?

Comment: For others finding this, it's currently not an option, and has been raised here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/92721/please-provide-an-option-to-disable-the-new-intell.html

Comment: Not only is it super annoying, it encourages poor coding practices.  The suggested names for DateTime for instance are terrible variable names.  Don't call your DateTime variable `date`; call it `hireDate` or `birthday` or something that tells you what the variable actually is.

Comment: and for Visual Basic.NET??????, that option does not exists for VB. Incredible.

Answer (score 4):

In the case, someone finds this post:
[image: Disable Name Suggestions]

I don't know since when this is available, I'm on: VS2017 Professional 15.8.8

Comment: Thanks, it's called 'Show name suggestions' in the equivalent English version.

Comment: In Spanish, it's `Opciones` -> `Editor de texto` -> `C#` -> `IntelliSense`, the `Mostrar sugerencias de nombres` checkbox.

Comment: and for Visual Basic.NET??????, that option does not exists for VB. Incredible.

Comment: @ElektroStudios these suggestions base on the type of the variable which you enter before the name in C# (MyType myType). Since in VB you enter the name of the variable first (myType as MyType), the IDE has no clue about the type of the variable/member/parameter, so what should it suggest?

Comment: @dba I was referring to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62178455/disable-favorite-suggestions-in-intellisense-for-visual-studio-2019 - thanks for comment!

Comment: ah ok, that's another topic :)

Answer (score 1):

Please uncheck "Inconsistent Naming" if you use Resharper.

> options -> Inspection Severity -> C# -> Constraints Violations -> Inconsistent Naming

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

1. Options
2. Text Editor
3. Choose language
4. IntelliSense
5. Unchecked 'Show name suggestions'

[image]