# Disable "favorite" (★) suggestions in IntelliSense for Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2019, intellisense, autosuggest

In Visual Studio 2019, how can someone disable the "favorite" (★) suggested names on auto-completion?. These suggestions inside the red square and ONLY these:

[image]

It is the most annoying feature.

If important: I need to disable it for VB.NET and then for C# too.

Comment: `Tools > Options > IntelliCode`. You can read all about this feature [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/services/intellicode/).

Comment: @Ahmed Abdelhameed thank you!, the options were inside "IntelliSense completions" -> "C# base model" and "Visual Basic model", once disabled it only disables those suggestions with a ★ in the left. Maybe you want to publish an answer then I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Disable “favorite” (★) suggestions in IntelliSense for Visual Studio
>   2019?

**First**, thanks to **Ahmed** for sharing the useful suggestions and his help.

★ is the feature of IntelliCode and it will put your most likely Suggestions to the top for easy use.

All of them are from the extension called [Visual Studio IntelliCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioExptTeam.VSIntelliCode).

You can find it under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions**-->**Installed**

[image]

> If important: I need to disable it for VB.NET and then for C# too

**Solution**

**Tools**-->**Options**-->**IntelliCode**-->**General** and disable these options:

[image]

**In addition**, if you do not want to use the whole `IntelliCode`, you can just disable that extension under **Manage Extensions UI**.