# How can I disable IntelliSense context-aware code completions?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, intellisense, code-completion

Starting with Visual Studio 2019, IntelliSense provides some kind of "favorites" above the list of available completions, tagged with a asterisk.

[image]

I feel these favorites are very annoying. They are disturbing my cognitive workflow when I'm searching for items alphabetically.

I couldn't find an option in `Tools > Options` to disable these context-aware code completions.

How can I disable these context-aware code completions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable "favorite" (★) suggestions in IntelliSense for Visual Studio 2019?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62178455/disable-favorite-suggestions-in-intellisense-for-visual-studio-2019)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I disable IntelliSense context-aware code completions?

The ★ function is from the vs extension called [Visual Studio IntelliCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioExptTeam.VSIntelliCode).

If you want to disable this, you could enter **Extensions**-->**Installed** and then disable that extension:

[image]

Then, restart VS and you will not see that.

**Besides**, if you want to disable Intellisense automatic completion function, you could click `Edit`-->`Intellisense`--> `Toggle Completion Mode`.

**In addition**, if you want to disable that Intellisense completion pop-up box, please enter `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Text Editor`-->`c#`-->`General`--> uncheck `Auto list members` option

Comment: Excellent answer! Great relief.